React Native Google task integration
I try to receive the list of google task from react native app.
I created a new app :
npx react-native init GoogleTasksApp

Added the package :
npm install @react-native-google-signin/google-signin axios

And rewrite the App.tsx:
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Button, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {
  GoogleSignin,
  statusCodes,
} from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';
import axios from 'axios';

const GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID =
  '38819132xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxogleusercontent.com';
const GOOGLE_ANDROID_CLIENT_ID =
  '38819132xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs.googleusercontent.com';

const App = () => {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    GoogleSignin.configure({
      scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
      ],
      webClientId: GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
    });
  }, []);

  const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      setUserInfo(userInfo);
      fetchTasks(userInfo.idToken);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error :', error);
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        console.log('User cancelled the login flow');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        console.log('Sign in is in progress already');
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        console.log('Play services not available or outdated');
      } else {
        console.log('Some other error happened:', error);
      }
    }
  };


  const fetchTasks = async token => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists',
        {
          headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
        },
      );
      setTasks(response.data.items);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching tasks:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      {userInfo ? (
        <View>
          <Text>Welcome, {userInfo.user.name}</Text>
          <FlatList
            data={tasks}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
          />
        </View>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Button title="Sign in with Google" onPress={signIn} />
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

I can receive the user data, but when I try to get list of tasks, I get an http 401 error with this token.
Task API is enabled in Google console. I created OAuth credentials for web, Android try to use it - same http 401 error.
What do I need to do to get list of tasks, with what type of api_key? What do I need to change in Google console to make it work?

GoogleSignin.signIn() return autorisationToken
to make request to google api need to use accessToken
it can be received with command const tokens = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
new working code:
      ...
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      setUserInfo(userInfo);
      const tokens = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
      fetchTasks(tokens.accessToken);
      ...

